# How to handle Git conflicts when deploying updates to production server

Tags: git, workflow, bitbucket

I'm very new to using Git, but want to implement it into my workflow for pushing updates to the production server.

I'll simplify it a little here, and skip the unimportant details, but basically I have figured this much out so far without any problems.

We have two Git branches, one for production, and one for development. The plan is that anytime we merge the development branch into the production branch, the changes would get synced to the production server.

Using scripts and web hooks with BitBucket I know how to make all of that work.

What I'm not sure how to handle is updating the site in this manner after the first initial sync. Once we have the new website synced to the server, and it's up and running, there are things like log files that get created on the production server, and some of these can be changing on a very consistent basis depending on what the files are for.

If I understand Git correctly, if I try to pull files down from BitBucket, but there are files on the production server that are not in the Git, it will show a warning about uncommitted changes or something.

So with a workflow like this how do you handle the files on the production server that get created or modified directly on the production server and are not contained in the Git archive?

Also, if it seems like I am missing something obvious, or there's a problem you see with this type of workflow, feel free to share your thoughts. As I've said, I've very new to Git, but I really like the concept and think it would be a great tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

You want to move the log files into a different location.  There's no way that you could even contemplate trying to commit the updated log file and then pull because the log file would already have been changed.

If you did a git --reset the logfile would revert to the last point you ever saved, losing activity, which wouldn't be good either.

Basically, any file that's being modified on the production server for production usage shouldn't be part of your git repo.  If it's not being tracked, you could leave it in the same tree with the rest of the repo, just know that git --status is going to show ?? and you risk inadvertenly adding/committing it.

Comment: This is what I was thinking.

Comment: I was just reading about .gitignore files. If I were to set up a list of the log files, and other files on the production server I wanted Git to leave alone and ignore, do you know if I would just put that .gitignore file on the production server, or would I add it to Git repository like the rest of my files?

Comment: .gitignore would be appropriate before actually commiting anything to the repo in the first place, but when it sounds like is that the logfiles are already in the repo and not sure if .gitignore works well after the fact....something to experiment with, I guess, but still don't like seeing log files in the repo.

Comment: We're putting this in place with the launch of a new site. So when we launch the new site we will be deleting all of the files from the production server and pulling them down through Git, and doing it that way going forward. So nothing has been committed or anything at all yet. So would I create the .gitignore file and commit that to the repo, telling it to ignore certain files/folders on the production server, or do I place the .gitignore file directly on the production server before pulling the files from the Git repo.

Comment: I'm just not sure if the .gitognore files goes IN the repository, or on the machine where the files to be ignored will be.

Comment: There can be a global .or repo, I've always included my .gitignores in the actual repo itself so anyone cloning the repo gets the same definition (i.e., skipping the same file).  The problem with anything global is making sure it gets in all instances on all servers.

Comment: Ok, so to make sure I understand correctly. The files we want to ignore will ONLY exist on the production server, so they will not be included in the repo itself. So if I create a .gitignore file with my list of file paths on the production server, and add it to the repo, and those files do not exist in the repo anyways, when I pull files from the repo to my production server for future updates Git will just ignore the fact that the log files on the server are not in the repo and will merge the rest of the changed files, leaving the log files and other ignored files as they were before?

Comment: Is my understanding of how the .gitignore file works from my last comment correct?